# How can I remove clickable hyperlinks in references while keeping all other hyperlinks in my document?

Tags: biblatex, hyperref, cross-referencing, hyperlink, url

I want to use hyperref in order to create hyperlinks so I can, say, click on a reference to an equation and jump to that equation, or to click on a citation in the text and jump to that reference in the bibliography.

However, I DO NOT want the references in the bibliography themselves to be "clickable", meaning they link to an external website containing the original reference.

I am using

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=phys, biblabel=brackets, sorting=nyt, 
doi=false, isbn=false, url=false]{biblatex}
```

Including `hyperref=false` in biblatex removes the clickable hyperlinks in the references, however also the hyperlinks from the text TO the references, which I want to keep.

The only solution I have found is manually commenting both `doi` and `url` in my .bib file, which is  tedious.

Comment: Do you still want to see the links printed but just want them to be un-clickable or do you want to completely hide URL, DOI and friends (you are already using the right option to hide most of the links with `doi=false, url=false,`, but by default URLs for the `@online` type are never hidden.)

Comment: Maybe the line `\let\url\gobble` just before `\bibliography{...}` is enough already? (Didn't test.)

Comment: @moewe I don't want the links displayed, and this is already implemented. However, the journal title, for example "Phys. Rev. Lett. XYZ, 123456 (2020)" is clickable and hyperlinks to a website with the reference.

Comment: @AlexG Unfortunately, that does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`biblatex-phys` links parts of the bibliography entry using the `doi/url-link` field format.

If you don't want that you can just redefine the field format to do nothing with

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{doi/url-link}{#1}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=phys, biblabel=brackets, sorting=nyt, 
doi=false, isbn=false, url=false]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\DeclareFieldFormat{doi/url-link}{#1}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Entry without link.]

---

Alternatively, you can get a bit more aggressive about removing `url` and `doi` by using a Biber sourcemap.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=phys, biblabel=brackets, sorting=nyt]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps{
    \map{
      \step[fieldset=isbn, null]
    }
    \map{
      \pernottype{online}
      \step[fieldset=doi, null]
      \step[fieldset=eprint, null]
      \step[fieldset=url, null]
      \step[fieldset=urldate, null]
    }
  }
}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```