# Remove clickable links on citations to the bibliography

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, natbib

Similar to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/567908/how-can-i-remove-clickable-hyperlinks-in-references-while-keeping-all-other-hype), but I am wondering how to stop citations from being links to the bibliography. I do not want my reader to click a reference and end up in my bibliography (or a website for that matter).

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,openany,a4paper,
                english, oldfontcommands
                ]{memoir}

\usepackage[PhD, goldenblock]{usthesis}                         
\usepackage[english]{babel} %.. Language setup
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}%.. Recognizes Ãª, Ã«, etc
\usepackage{amsmath} %.. Advanced maths (before fonts)
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %.. Type 1 fonts for proper hyphenation
\usepackage{textcomp} %.. Additional text characters
\usepackage{fourier} %.. Utopia (if you want a different font)
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Introduction}
\section{Para}
Loremipsum \citet{so_2012}

\bibliography{dissertation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: In particular please clarify which bibliography tool you use. The site you linked to uses biblatex, but your question is tagged with bibtex. Please clarify!

Comment: Given that you are not using any options for `hyperref` you get the standard colored boxes around hyperlins (or what ever your PDF viewer is doing). Might be an idea to change the default into some non-intrusive colors with no boxes.

Comment: I'm aware that I could change the colours of the citation links etc. but I'd prefer them to not be read as links to other parts of the document/the bibliography at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quick hack to switch off the links for citations:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,openany,a4paper,
                english, oldfontcommands
                ]{memoir}

\usepackage[PhD, goldenblock]{usthesis}                         
\usepackage[english]{babel} %.. Language setup
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}%.. Recognizes Ãª, Ã«, etc
\usepackage{amsmath} %.. Advanced maths (before fonts)
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %.. Type 1 fonts for proper hyphenation
\usepackage{textcomp} %.. Additional text characters
\usepackage{fourier} %.. Utopia (if you want a different font)
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\hyper@natanchorstart[1]{} 
\renewcommand\hyper@natanchorend{} 
\renewcommand\hyper@natlinkstart[1]{} 
\renewcommand\hyper@natlinkend{} 
\renewcommand\hyper@natlinkbreak[2]{#1}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Loremipsum \citet{knuth}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{document}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Works an absolute charm, thank you!

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: I think it is clearer to set the natbib hooks back to their default values: `\renewcommand\hyper@natanchorstart[1]{}
\renewcommand\hyper@natanchorend{}
\renewcommand\hyper@natlinkstart[1]{}
\renewcommand\hyper@natlinkend{}
\renewcommand\hyper@natlinkbreak[2]{#1}`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank for your suggestion!

Answer (score 3):

Please try adding the following to the preamble:

```
\usepackage[options]{nohyperref}
```

This should remove all links

Comment: This seems to be the nuclear option, apologies as I didn't add a table of contents to the above (which I would like to have links).

Comment: Is there an option in nohyperref that allows me to only not link the citations?

Answer (score -2):

EDIT:
Found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1562086/latex-disable-or-turn-off-hyperlinking-for-table-of-contents). They suggest to use the `hypertoc` parameter with the hyperref package as such:
`\usepackage[linktoc=none]{hyperref}`.

The following you already answered in the comments, but I'll leave it up for others to read. I asked why you wouldn't want the reader to easily get to the right references in your bibliography by clicking? It's a function that really conveniences the whole search for specific citations.

Answer: Kindle readers have trouble with this mechanic.

Comment: Indeed, this is not an answer. Therefore, you should no have posted it as if it was.

Comment: Clicking a link and ending up in the bibliography can be incredibly annoying for kindle readers such as myself, hence my question.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos, can't comment yet (not enough reputation) so I thought I would ask a genuine question this way.

Comment: @AndrewEarl, thanks, hadn't considered kindle readers. Maybe an option on the device itself?

Comment: @AndrewEarl how exactly are these links annoying to kindle readers?

Comment: @daleif because as a kindle reader I've touched a citation by accident and ended up in my bibliography.

Comment: @AndrewEarl I would not say that is a true argument. That happens on all touch devices.

Comment: @daleif sure. But I am not posing an argument, I am asking whether it is possible to remove a certain feature in hyperref because of how I would like my document to read, based on my preferences.

Comment: @AndrewEarl but are you the only one reading the document? You should be much more clear in the phrasing of your question.